# Why i am getting undefined in the alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I want to display alert when someone chose both options from the html select option element what they have chosen. but my function are not working properly in my exchange function  there the alert i am getting is "you want to change From  undefined     To   undefined ". The variable I set on the exchange function from and to is getting replace by undefined. But I don't understand why this is happening i have declared them already.

```
$( ".my_Class1" ).each(function( index ) { 
          $( this ).on("change",choice_1) 
    });
    
    function  choice_1(){ 
      var from = this.value;
      return from;
    }
    
    
    $( ".my_Class2" ).each(function( index ) {
          $( this ).on("change",choice_2)
    });
    
    function  choice_2(){ 
      var to = this.value;
      return to;
    }
    function exchange() { 
        var first = choice_1(); 
        var second = choice_2();  
        
      if(first === second){
          alert("you want to change From " + first  + " To " + second); //in alert in the browser " You want to change from undefined to undefined"
    
    
        }else{
      
           alert("you want to change From " + first + " To " + second); // Here Also getting the same 
          }
        }
    
      $( ".my_Class1, my_Class2" ).each(function( index ) {
            $( this ).on("change", exchange)
      });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Without seeing your HTML, there is no way can test this. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Because `this` binds to the caller's scope. So, by the time `choice_1()` executed `this` points to the `extchange()` scope and not to element. Add `const that = this;` next to `choice_1()` and then use `that.value` instead;

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you call `var first = choice_1();` in your `exchange()` function, the `choice_1()` function refers to `this` which has no real context when you call it from within `exchange()`.

When you call it from the `on change` event, it makes sense. The `this` context is the selected option.

So one possible solution is to call `exchange()` from within your `choice_1()` and `choice_2()` functions where `from` and `to` can be passed on with the correct context.

Here's a partial refactoring of your code which should show the options you selected in the alert. Be aware that no option is preselected on page load, so the first time you select an option the other value will be `undefined`.

```js
var from, to;

function choice_1() {
  from = this.value;
  exchange(from, to)
}

function choice_2() {
  to = this.value;
  exchange(from, to)
}

function exchange(from, to) {
  alert("you want to change From " + from + " To " + to);
}

$(".my_Class1").each(function(index) {
  $(this).on("change", choice_1)
});

$(".my_Class2").each(function(index) {
  $(this).on("change", choice_2)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>From</label>
<select class="my_Class1">
<option>Select</option>
<option value="a">A</option>
<option value="b">B</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<label>To</label>
<select class="my_Class2">
<option>Select</option>
<option value="a">A</option>
<option value="b">B</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Everthing is fine here but i want it in one single alert here what i wantis the alert should pop up after both option is selected how to achieve that ? it will be great to know ..